# Forcing PHPExcel file to be saved and downloaded

Tags: download, export, phpexcel

With one of my projects I have users 'export' information into Excel files using PHPExcel. When it works, it works perfectly.  Other times, only some people can actually open the files.

Since I need to store the exports that are created, they are saved on the server and then the created file is downloaded using readfile(). When it doesn't work, (which is most of the time now) people get the 'wrong file format' error.  The really odd thing is that since the file is saved, they can try downloading that same file again.  Then it works.

Here is my final save and download code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$Temp_Export_File_Name.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
//$objWriter->save('php://output');
$objWriter->save('../project_files_images/created_exports/'.$Temp_Export_File_Name);
readfile('../project_files_images/created_exports/'.$Temp_Export_File_Name);
exit;
```

Is there something wrong with this code that I am missing? The problem tends to show itself most for users of the latest versions of Office (Mac or Windows)

Thanks for the input.

Comment: Open one of these problem files in a text editor and look for any whitespace characters at the beginning and end of the file, or for any obvious PHP error messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mark's tip was correct.  For anyone else that might run into this, here is what was happening.

PHPExcel, for some reason, requires a 'Creator' and 'Last Modified By' field and I am not using them.  I simply commented out the 2 lines of code within the PHPExcel code which referred to these 2 items.

It still doesn't explain why it effected the forced file and not the saved file, but the theory I am running with is this.

1. The saved file was created by all the header information set and saved.
2. The forced file somehow included the printed errors on the head of the file.

Comment: Anything that is sent to "screen" by PHP is sent to the standard php://output stream.... this includes error messages and warnings. When you direct the PHPExcel file save to the same output stream, it will include the binary stream from PHPExcel as well as those error messages and warnings. You're using the headers to tell the browser that the output is a file, so you don't see this on screen. The inclusion of those messages in the output mean it's no longer a valid Excel file. When you save to a file, error/warning messages still go to php://output and are displayed on screen, not to the file

Comment: Thank you for explaining and helping it all make sense. Why don't you explain it as an answer so that I can give you the credit. :)